# Can't save fields

Tags: craft3, field

I want to change some fields and when I click 'save' it goes to the list of fields and the changes aren't saved. I can't add fields either. I can add and edit entries for example.

Comment: What version of Craft are you on? Any errors being logged in Craft's `storage/logs` folder?

Comment: 3.1.27
There is couple of files. Which one do you mean exactly?

Comment: Check whatever files' modification date updates when you click save.

Comment: Best solution for that is to delete all of the files in logs/ folder, and after, save the field again. Now the new file in logs/ will have only that error.